# Unity 2022.3.13f1 unable to override the NetworkManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I'm trying to follow the documentation to override the OnServerAddPlayer method. I need to spawn player prefabs based of their `PlayerType`. I've tried following [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManager.html) documentation. See: "Customizing Player Instantiation". I'm unable to find the `NetworkServer` class in Unity it also seems that this page doesn't exist: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection.html

Have they moved the NetworkServer to a new place? How will this even work if this is the docs for Unity 2022.3?

Comment: [`NetzworkServer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkServer.html) => `Important: UNet is a deprecated solution, and a new Multiplayer and Networking
Solution (Netcode for GameObjects) is under development. For more information and next steps see the information on the Unity Netcode for GameObjects website.`

Comment: was gonna say the first screen says decpreciated use netcode.. theres a lot of info on netcode

Comment: Thank you aswell! Hadn't notice the deprecated message. I'm happy to find that Netcode for Gameobjects also does what I'm looking for in my problem. @BugFinder